# Beautifulsoup FindAll by class attribute

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have an html code as follows:

```
<div class="_cFb">  
<div class="_XWk">Rabindranath Tagore</div>
</div>
```

I have used the following python code for extracting the text content:

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'._XWk'})
```

This code returns empty. However I am able to access other class atrributes that doesnt begin with an underscore(_). Any ideas to extract the tag text?

Comment: You have a `.` in front of the class name. Perhaps removing it would help?

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''<div class="_cFb">  
... <div class="_XWk">Rabindranath Tagore</div>
... </div>''', 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find_all('div', class_='_XWk')
[<div class="_XWk">Rabindranath Tagore</div>]
```

Found the way to search by class here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

By the way, lxml framework, which also can be used for parsing HTML, allows using CSS selectors for searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [87]: soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'_XWk'})
```

remove the `.` in the `._XWk`